# How to figure out which button was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Hello I have a form which has two buttons. 
In the form validation (onsubmit callback),
I would like to know which of the two submit buttons which both share the same name were clicked.

How can I do that using JQuery?

Comment: I did not find the answer on google quick, so I do not delete my question. The answer is just using the onclick function of the button what I tried first but somehow it did not work at the first try. But that is the correct solution.

Please do not vote me down for that question xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnKE3/) Link

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" name="sameName" class="buttonClass" id="Button1" value="Button1">
<input type="button" name="sameName" class="buttonClass" id="Button2" value="Button2">
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".buttonClass").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id")+" clicked");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("id") == "some_id") {
    // Do something ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target` (assuming the callback's argument is called event.): http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 0):

make use of `this` as

```
var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
```